# How to convert from array of json object to String in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, node-modules

I'm getting response from HTTP post as array of json objects. but want to display as string. Please see my response..

```
{ total: 14,
  results:
   [ { name: [Object],
       comments: [],
       attributes: [Object],
       type: [Object],
       context: [Object],
       status: 'Accepted',
       score: 1.7646775,
       modified: 1426085315767,
       parents: [] },
     { name: [Object],
       comments: [],
       attributes: [Object],
       type: [Object],
       context: [Object],
       status: 'Accepted',
       score: 1.3945999,
       modified: 1425386916807,
       parents: [] },
```

Below code to display response.

```
function(error, response, data){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
          console.log(data);

}
```

Comment: Can you just use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: You can do that with map: `const arrAsStr = arr.map( (r) => JSON.stringify(r) );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NodeJS has ES5 `JSON` class which has `stringify()` method in it

```
function(error, response, data){
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Great. Its working ..How to get specific field value from json ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` will take any javascript object and convert it into a json string. so it access a property inside JSON string you have to parse it back to js object. you can do this using `JSON.parse("json string goes here")`